# Using cron to schedule bash script that activates virtual env and starts Django server

Tags: python, django, linux, bash

I am trying to schedule a cron job to start a Django server but not having any luck. The code below works in terminal when I type `bash filename.sh` but my cron job `02 9 * * * bash home/user/filename.sh` doesn't work.

The filename.sh script:

```
#!bin/bash
source activate my_env
cd folder
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the complete paths (for python and manage.py) without activating the enviroment, for example:

```
/home/user/.environment/your_env/bin/python /home/user/project_path/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! I have a few questions (sorry if super basic, trying to learn this stuff). So now the django server is up and everything works. (1) how do i see the terminal shell where it exists and/or kill

Comment: I suggest you to use a process manager like *supervisord* in order to properly manage the django server process.

Comment: Also I can suggest to spawn the wsgi process with uwsgi or gunicorn if you want to speed up the requests, with runserver you spawn 1 process, with uwsgi you can multiple.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
. /path_to_your_installation/my_env/bin/activate && python /path_to_your_installation/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```